# Alternate Definition of a Finite Dimensional Vector Space and why is this not used?

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook defines a finite dimensional vector space as follows:

> The vector space $V(F)$ is said to be finite dimensional or finitely generated if there exists a finite subset $S$ of $V(F)$ such that $V=L(S).$

I was wondering why didn't the author use the following definition, which I think is equivalent:

> The vector space $V(F)$ is said to be finite dimensional or finitely generated if the basis of the vector space is finite.

Is there any specific reason or is it just author's choice?

Comment: Well, to write "the" in the second yellow area is confusing and clumsy, to say the least, as in most cases there is no **the** basis, but *a* basis. And the rest of the wording is also not very clear and "tighten". Much better, accurate and precise the first one.

Comment: What means $L(S)$ ? The set of $F$-linear combinations of the elements of $S$ ? Both definitions are obviously equivalent. A $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space is of the form $\{\sum_{m=1}^n c_m \alpha_m, c_n \in F\}$ where $c_{m'}$ cannot be written in the form $\sum_{m=1, m \ne m'}^n c_m$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the reason is that, at that point, the first author has not proven that every basis of a vector space has the same cardinal. Note that, in the second definition, they talk about **the** basis. That would not be a correct definition if we didn't know about that result.

Comment: nice, although they dont call it "the basis" usually.

Answer (score 1):

we can prove that every finitely generated vector space has a basis and then prove that they all have the same size.

It wuld be a lot more awkward to first start only with vector spaces that have a basis.

If you want to get a grasp of what the above looks like you may want to learn some module theory, modules with finite basis are called free modules of finite dimension.